# Relationship between Bernoulli and Normal CDF

Tags: normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, bernoulli-distribution

Is there any relationship between the draw from a Bernoulli with parameter $p$ and the Normal CDF. Specifically is the condition $p>\Phi(x)$, where $x$ is drawn from the standard normal distribution, equivalent to a draw from Bernoulli$(p)$ ?

Comment: The notion / notation "p > cdf(x)" is unfamiliar to me. Can you clarify your situation? Are you thinking in terms of a strategy to simulate Bernoulli data by drawing a normal random variate & assigning a $1$ if it's > some threshold & $0$ otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any relationship between the draw from a Bernoulli with parameter p and the Normal CDF.

Yes, but usually it's not terribly interesting on its own.

There are some contexts where relationships between variables might make use of such a relationship (such as a probit regression for binomial data, or in some correlation measures involving one or both variables being binary).

> Specifically is the condition p > cdf(x) where x is drawn from the standard normal distribution equivalent to a draw from Bernoulli(p) ?

If the cdf you mean is the standard normal cdf, $\Phi$, then $\Phi(X)$ is a (continuous) uniform on (0,1). See [Probability Integral Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform).

You can generate Bernoulli random variables with parameter $p$ by generating uniform and comparing the uniform against $p$... however, the way it works is if $U>p$ you generate a 0; if $U\leq p$ you generate a 1. This corresponds to the [inverse-cdf method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#Generation_from_a_probability_distribution) of random number generation (at least, it is with a minor algebraic fiddle).

So if you're using this as a source of Bernoulli random numbers, it's a very inefficient way of proceeding: generating normal random numbers, turning your normal values into uniform values and using uniforms to get the Bernoulli random numbers. You might as well just generate uniforms directly and avoid a lot of mucking about.